# How to compare rows from JSON file in angular?

Tags: json, angular5, lodash

I have this items in a JSON file that I need to compare wherever I have Curr or Prev values and compare if they are equals. this algorithm is with angular 5 but I'm being unable to do this, I did the load function with httpClient
Example :

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "comparisonDate": "2017-06-22",
    "milestone": "CURR_PREV",
    "udDomain": "BASIS",
    "udIdentifier": "332A251000.01",
    "rpt": "D70",
    "approvedCurr": true,
    "approvedPrev": null,
    "commercialReferenceCurr": "BASIS - 01.01.2007",
    "commercialReferencePrev": null,
    "customizationImpactCurr": null,
    "customizationImpactPrev": null,
    "deliveryTypeCurr": null,
    "deliveryTypePrev": null,
    "aircraftId": 184,
    "aircraftSapId": "580652",
    "aircraftName": "BUL 011",
    "aircraftSerialNumber": "02713",
    "quantityCurr": "1",
    "quantityPrev": null,
    "statusCurr": "O",
    "statusPrev": null,
    "typeModification": "CREATION",
    "validityCurr": "V",
    "validityPrev": null
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "comparisonDate": "2017-06-22",
    "milestone": "CURR_PREV",
    "udDomain": "BASIS",
    "udIdentifier": "332A270028.01",
    "rpt": "E15",
    "approvedCurr": true,
    "approvedPrev": null,
    "commercialReferenceCurr": "BASIS - 01.01.2007",
    "commercialReferencePrev": null,
    "customizationImpactCurr": null,
    "customizationImpactPrev": null,
    "deliveryTypeCurr": null,
    "deliveryTypePrev": null,
    "aircraftId": 184,
    "aircraftSapId": "580652",
    "aircraftName": "BUL 011",
    "aircraftSerialNumber": "02713",
    "quantityCurr": "1",
    "quantityPrev": null,
    "statusCurr": "O",
    "statusPrev": null,
    "typeModification": "CREATION",
    "validityCurr": "V",
    "validityPrev": null
}]
```

this should be with using lodash.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume your want something like this

- for each object in your array
- filter keys that end with "Curr"
- for each get Prev property
- compare it with curr property

  ```
  let obj = [{
  "id": 1,
  "comparisonDate": "2017-06-22",
  "milestone": "CURR_PREV",
  "udDomain": "BASIS",
  "udIdentifier": "332A251000.01",
  "rpt": "D70",
  "approvedCurr": true,
  "approvedPrev": null,
  "commercialReferenceCurr": "BASIS - 01.01.2007",
  "commercialReferencePrev": null,
  "customizationImpactCurr": null,
  "customizationImpactPrev": null,
  "deliveryTypeCurr": null,
  "deliveryTypePrev": null,
  "aircraftId": 184,
  "aircraftSapId": "580652",
  "aircraftName": "BUL 011",
  "aircraftSerialNumber": "02713",
  "quantityCurr": "1",
  "quantityPrev": null,
  "statusCurr": "O",
  "statusPrev": null,
  "typeModification": "CREATION",
  "validityCurr": "V",
  "validityPrev": null
  }, {
  "id": 2,
  "comparisonDate": "2017-06-22",
  "milestone": "CURR_PREV",
  "udDomain": "BASIS",
  "udIdentifier": "332A270028.01",
  "rpt": "E15",
  "approvedCurr": true,
  "approvedPrev": null,
  "commercialReferenceCurr": "BASIS - 01.01.2007",
  "commercialReferencePrev": null,
  "customizationImpactCurr": null,
  "customizationImpactPrev": null,
  "deliveryTypeCurr": null,
  "deliveryTypePrev": null,
  "aircraftId": 184,
  "aircraftSapId": "580652",
  "aircraftName": "BUL 011",
  "aircraftSerialNumber": "02713",
  "quantityCurr": "1",
  "quantityPrev": null,
  "statusCurr": "O",
  "statusPrev": null,
  "typeModification": "CREATION",
  "validityCurr": "V",
  "validityPrev": null
   }];


  obj.forEach(x=>{
    Object.keys(x)
     .filter(y=>y.endsWith("Curr"))
     .forEach(y=>{
       let prevProp = y.replace("Curr", "Prev")
       console.log(y, x[y]);
       console.log(prevProp ,x[prevProp ]);
       if(x[y]===x[prevProp ]){
         //equal
       }else{
         //not equal
       }
   })

  })
  ```

you could use lodash's _.forEach, _.Keys, _.filter but i think there is not much point on this.